# .NET nanoFramework-checksum errors at deployment

Tags: .net, esp32

I'm trying to flash a .NET program for my ESP32-WROOM-32 board, but I get the following output at deployment process. I'm using the latest version of the following NuGet packages:

**nanoFramework.CoreLibrary, nanoFramework.Runtime.Events, nanoFramework.System.Device.Gpio**

```
Build started at 18:39...
1>------ Deploy started: Project: ESPTest, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Getting things ready to deploy assemblies to .NET nanoFramework device: ESP32 @ COM5.
1>Deploy failed.
1>
1>***************************************************************************
1>
1>The connected target has the wrong version for the following assembly(ies):
1>
1>    'mscorlib' requires native v100.5.0.19, checksum 0x445C7AF9.
1>    Connected target has v100.5.0.17, checksum 0x004CF1CE.
1>
1>    'System.Device.Gpio' requires native v100.1.0.6, checksum 0x097E7BC5.
1>    Connected target has v100.1.0.4, checksum 0xB6D0ACC1.
1>
1>Please check: 
1>  1) if the target is running the most updated image.
1>  2) if the project is referring the appropriate version of the NuGet package.
1>
1>Our Visual Studio FAQ has a troubleshooting guide: https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/faq/working-with-vs-extension.html
1>
1>***************************************************************************
1>
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 18:39 and took 00,388 seconds ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy completed at 18:39 and took 00,388 seconds ==========
```

Can you please help me?

Thank you in advance!